# Android-Studio: List<Integer> crashing my app

Tags: android, list, crash

I am currently working on implementing a checkbox into my listview. But i need to get info, which checkboxes were tagged before scrolling. All works fine, but when I try to add item to List my app crashes.

```
public class viewHolder {
        ToggleButton favorite;
        TextView text;
        List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(1,2,5);
    }
```

And when app crashes when I call

```
viewHolder.intList.add(position);
```

Crash code

```
04-14 14:01:36.097 14198-14198/com.joudoviny.jonda.copypasta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.joudoviny.jonda.copypasta, PID: 14198
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at com.example.jonda.copypasta.MainActivity$MyListAdapter$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:667)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:134)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6637)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: look at the error you are getting

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please be a bit more specific, how the crash looks like? Do you have  a stacktrace that you could post?

Comment: Updated the question with crash info. IntList works fine (when checking the checkboxes) but the error only happens when I try to add an integer to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Arrays.asList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) returns a fixed size list. You are not allowed to add items.

You could wrap the result in a new [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), e.g.

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,5));
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays.asList returns a non resizable list.

Use this instead

`= new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))`